# Is there a way to run azure-devops pipeline from python?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multiple pipelines with scripts defined on my azure devops.
I would like to be able to run them from my local machine using python.
Is this possible?
If yes, how to achieve it?

Regards,
Maciej

Answer (score 0):

You can't run them in this way that you will take YAML code and put it python or actually any language and run it locally. You need to build agent to run your pipeline. So you can create a pool, install agent on you local machine, change your pipeline to use this pool.

Comment: Thanks, Krzysztof, for your response! Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have pipeline with YAML prepared on Azure DevOps. I'm able to run it from the Azure DevOps site. But now I would like to trigger this pipeline with python code from my local machine. Probably using Azure REST API. But I have no experience with it and I'm looking for the help.